# error C3767 on richTextBox SetStyle

Tags: visual-c++, richtextbox

Please Help, SetStyle returns an error, "error, C3767: 'System::Windows::Forms::Control::SetStyle': canididate function(s) not accessible", and I have no idea how to fix it, I searched every "C3767" error fix on stackoverflow, and I got nothing.
Code:

```
this->richTextBox1->SetStyle(ControlStyles::SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
richTextBox1->BackColor = Color::Transparent;
```

Comment: This is a bit like trying `pig->SetStyle(CanFly)`. `SetStyle` is for the control to tell the framework what features it wants to support - not for the user to magically make the control support a feature it isn't designed for. `SetStyle` is a protected member, specifically to prevent you from calling it.

Comment: Lol, **PIGS CAN FLY!** So, what can I use to make it true?

Comment: Yes, [with sufficient thrust.](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1925) In straight Windows API, there exists such a thing as a [windowless rich edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787609.aspx). It renders text on whatever surface you provide; I'm pretty sure you can achieve a transparent background effect with it. But I have no idea whether or how it could be used in .Net.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Hmmm... is it possible to make the richTextBoxes Background Image the image of the nice cyan-blue background?